# DataWeave 2.0 Backslash escaping

Tags: mule, dataweave

How can you get a single backslash in DataWeave 2.0?

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{
  "attempt1": "\String",
  "attempt2": "\\String"
}
```

Returns:

```
{
  "attempt1": "\\String",
  "attempt2": "\\String"
}
```

Comment: Added output mimetype for clarification

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like your output is a json and in [json](https://www.json.org) the \ always need to be escaped inside a string. That is why you are always going to see two \